# Plugin to check for broken links?

Tags: plugins

Is there a plugin, similar to https://wordpress.org/plugins/broken-link-checker/ or other Wordpress plugins, that can test links in the database and report which ones are broken? It doesn't have to be pretty or fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't seem to find a plugin that does this. I may build a link into the CP dashboard for a third party link-checking service like https://validator.w3.org/checklink, http://www.deadlinkchecker.com/website-dead-link-checker.asp, or http://www.brokenlinkcheck.com/. Or just recommend a browser extension that will do it on a page-by-page basis, like [Check My Links](http://www.brokenlinkcheck.com/) for Chrome.

Maybe once I get into plugin development, I'll make one myself. :)

Comment: Do you have any experience with any of those services – and if so, which one do you prefer?

Comment: I tried them all quickly while I was researching this, but I haven't used any regularly. I don't maintain any sites besides my own little business page (don't look at it! the cobbler's children have no shoes!) and I just recently realized it would be a good idea for my clients.

Answer (score 4):

nystudio107 has a great plugin that takes care of this and lets you implement redirects when broken links are found.

[retour on Github](https://github.com/nystudio107/retour)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Retour looks like a great tool for making sure internal links don't break, especially when slugs are changed - I'm looking forward to implementing it. Like Jeremy said though, it doesn't seem to check both internal AND external links, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi Katie - someone is very kindly generating reports for me actually - I don't have a personal paid account (yet?) - it does seem like a very good service!

Comment: While Retour doesn't scour for broken links, it _does_ automatically create a redirect if your entry's URL changes.

Answer (score 4):

(I don't think retour actually looks for broken links actively - it does log 404s coming in to your site though and make it easy to set up re-directs).

There are a number of online services that will spider your site and report on broken internal or external links - e.g. https://www.semrush.com

I am not aware of a plugin for Craft that does this directly by looking in the db as such.

Comment: Whoa, semrush is a cool service! I hadn't heard of it before. While I want to use it for analytics and SEO reporting now that I know about it, I can't find how to check broken links in it specifically. Is it available in the free version? Do you know what it's called in the menu?